# Calling another function on same composed function with Factory functions

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to get rid of the this keyword on the line:

```
this.getOscillatorConfig(oscNumber);
```

below?:

```
const oscPlayer = (audioContext, voiceConfig) => ({

    getOscillatorConfig(oscNumber)
    {
        return voiceConfig.oscillators[oscNumber];
    },

    getOscillator(oscNumber)
    {
        this.getOscillatorConfig(oscNumber);

        let vco = audioContext.createOscillator();
        vco.type = oscConfig.waveform;

        return vco;
    },

    start: (vco, time, noteLength, frequency) => {

        vco.frequency.value = frequency;

        vco.start(time);
        vco.stop(time + noteLength);
    }

});

const octave = () => ({
        applyPipeLength: (frequency, pipeLength) => {
        return frequency / (parseInt(pipeLength, 10) / 8);
    }
});

const Voice = (audioContext, voiceConfig)  => {

    return Object.assign(
        {},
        oscPlayer(audioContext, voiceConfig),
        octave()
    )
}
```

If I don't use it, I have getOscillatorConfig is undefined.

Or any other advice for how to structure this?

Comment: _"Is there a way..."_ Why do you want to get rid of the `this`?

Answer (score 1):

To be able to omit `this`, you have to create a function with name `getOscillatorConfig` that is available in the scope you want to call it:

```
const oscPlayer = (audioContext, voiceConfig) => {

    function getOscillatorConfig(oscNumber) {
        return voiceConfig.oscillators[oscNumber];
    }

    return {
        getOscillator(oscNumber) {
            getOscillatorConfig(oscNumber);

            let vco = audioContext.createOscillator();
            vco.type = oscConfig.waveform;

            return vco;
        },

        start(vco, time, noteLength, frequency) {
            // ...
        }
    };
};
```